# How to convert select statement result to JSONARRAY and update another table

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I want to convert  select result to JSON and write it to another table:

```sql
update patrol_patrol a, position_user b
set a.route = json_array(select coordinate from b )
where a.id = 1;
```

and get error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select coordinate from b ) where a.id = 1' at line 2
```

```
 select route from patrol_patrol;                                                                                                                                                    
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| route                                                                                                                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ["112.58006496213066,22.311484443420195"] |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set
```

```
 select coordinate from position_user;                                                                                                                                                    
+---------------------------------------+
| coordinate                            |
+---------------------------------------+
| 112.701036,22.738611                  |
| 112.701036,22.738632                  |
| 112.701036,22.738632                  |
| 112.701036,22.738652
```

position_user.coordinate should be ["112.701036,22.738611", "112.701036,22.738632", "112.701036,22.738652", ....] after update

Comment: are you updating or inserting?

Comment: your title says "while inserting"

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ Sorry. any one is OK

Comment: please update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only updating the `patrol_patrol` table, you should only include that in the first part of your update statement. To get what you're looking for, I recommend using the [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) function, which will combine your results into one array, which can then be used to assign the result to `a.route`:

```
UPDATE patrol_patrol a
SET a.route = (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(coordinate) FROM position_user)
WHERE a.id = 1;
```

A dbfiddle can be found [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sLWhRfMf6vok8KTaRbHeN3/0) demonstrating this approach.